# View Local PDF on android Webview using dropbox

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-webview, dropbox

I am currently developing an Android app that has the functionality to create a pdf based on a form. The pdf is saved locally.

From the research I've done It looks like you can only use the google URL to mount a pdf if it is stored online. correct me if I am wrong.

("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.example.com/xxxxxyyyyyxz.pdf")

I have chose to store the pdf locally to avoid devoting a file server for this. (Not that I have one anyway)

Is it possible temporarily store the PDF in dropbox - > pass the URL to the webview -> delete file once webview is closed.

And to do all this without allowing the user navigate through any other documents on dropbox.